# Adjusting dimensions of UIImageView when iPad is rotated to Landscape orientation

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiimageview, uipageviewcontroller

I have a simple app that displays a `UIPageViewController` when a cell is clicked on in a `UITableViewController`. The `UIPageViewController` (called `Leaflets`) shows 6 images in a very good layout for both the iPhone and iPad:

```
- (void)imageDimensions
{
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    CGRect insetFrame;
    if (IDIOM == IPAD)
    {
        NSLog(@"iPad");
        insetFrame = CGRectMake(160, 70, self.view.frame.size.width-320, self.view.frame.size.height-115);

    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"iPhone");
        insetFrame = CGRectMake(30, 20, self.view.frame.size.width-60, self.view.frame.size.height-15);

    }

    _imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:insetFrame];
    [_imageView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
    [_imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:_model.imageName]];
    [[self view] addSubview:_imageView];

}
```

When I rotate the iPad to `Landscape` mode, ideally, I want the `insetFrame` to change so that the image isn't stretched out across the screen.

I tried by putting a `NSNotification` in the `viewDidLoad`:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(deviceRotated:) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

Which calls:

```
-(void)deviceRotated:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    NSLog(@"Rotation");
    CGRect insetFrame;
    insetFrame = CGRectMake(160, 70, self.view.frame.size.width-620, self.view.frame.size.height-715);
    _imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:insetFrame];
    [_imageView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
    [_imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:_model.imageName]];
    [[self view] addSubview:_imageView];


}
```

The method here is definitely getting called but there are two issues.

**Issues**

Without adding the `imageView` to the view, nothing changes on the property go the image and if I keep the method how it's displayed above, it adds the image on top of the existing image.

Ideally, I'd like to remove the image from the view and reset it's coordinates for the portrait mode.

```
[_imageView removeFromSuperview];
```

If I set that in the `deviceRotated` method, it gets called each time the view is rotated, so it's always removing, etc.

I'd like a way to say, if landscape, show this frame and if portrait, show this frame.

Any guidance on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting the display up for redraw and relayout?

```
CGRect insetFrame;
insetFrame = CGRectMake(160, 70, self.view.frame.size.width-620, self.view.frame.size.height-715);
_imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:insetFrame];
[_imageView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
[_imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:_model.imageName]];
[_imageView setNeedsDisplay];
[_imageView setNeedsLayout];
```

This might work for you. Remove the [[self view] addSubview:_imageView] line for sure; you're adding it to the display repeatedly.

Comment: Thanks @Brooks - that's really helpful. So I am checking the orientation and applying the size appropriately and have put the setNeedsDisplay and setNeedsLayout which looks good. I am also removing the image from the superview (        [_imageView removeFromSuperview];) with the orientation, but sometimes when I rotate, the image doesn't get removed. Is there any way to remove the image completely, or to be sure the image will always be removed in rotation?

Comment: Good question. I would advise not removing the image from the UIImageView each time, just to get it to redraw.  Generally, if you cannot get your image to draw properly, it means you're missing out on something that UIKit gives you already. Something more simple. In this case, when the Notification comes through, there are a lot of calls being made to the ViewController. Try putting the size changes in viewDidLayoutSubviews method.

Comment: That's perfect man - I had to just check with the code but absolutely, removing the removal line of code made sure this was redrawing every time. Thanks for the help on this - really appreciate it!